# SQL Conversion function

Tags: oracle

to_char(date1,[format],[nls_parametr]) 
what is nls_parametr in here?

Comment: Its probably a list

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129)

> The 'nlsparam' argument specifies the language in which month and day names and abbreviations are returned. This argument can have this form:
>
> ```
> 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = language'
> ```